# How to dispatch a chained job in a loop?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I am trying to dispatch a Laravel job inside a foreach loop. But the problem is, when I dispatch job inside loop sometimes it is completed before jobs queued before it are completed. What I want that is jobs should be completed one by one. Like happens in the chain method. But How I chain the same job inside the foreach loop? Is this possible?

```
foreach ($consignments as $consignment) {
     CalculateSingleConsignment::dispatch($consignment, $total_consignments, $i, $user_id, $notify)->onQueue('invoice');
     $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct the array to be chained rather than dispatching the actual job in the loop:

```
$jobs = [];
 foreach (array_values($consignments) as $i => $consignment) { 
      $jobs[] = new CalculateSingleConsignment($consignment, $total_consignments, $i, $user_id, $notify);
}
Bus::chain($jobs)->onQueue('invoice')->dispatch()
```

If you want to use dependency injection you can construct your jobs as:

```
app()->makeWith(CalculateSingleConsignment::class, compact('consignment', 'total_consignments', 'i', 'user_id', 'notify'));
```

Comment: Can i use only first code for jobs . without dependency injection?

Comment: And what is `Bus`

Comment: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus` (according to https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-chaining), and yes you don't need to use dependency injection if your jobs don't need it